# HKR in characteristic p

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, differential-forms

Let $A$ be a commutative $k$-algebra where $k$ is a field. The HKR states that $HH_i (A) \simeq \Omega^i_{A/k}$. In characteristic $0$ the isomorphism is given by the formula $a_0 \otimes a_1 \otimes .. \otimes a_n \to \frac{1}{n!} a_0 da_1 .. da_n$ with the inverse given by the antisymmetrization map. My question is: can we write something similar in characteristic p at least for simple examples? For example, for the affine line $\mathbb{F}_p [x]$ we have $HH_1 (\mathbb{F}_p[x]) \simeq \Omega^1_{\mathbb{F}_p[x]}$ but what is the map here? The map from char $k$=$0$ case doesn't work (even for $n=1$) since $a \otimes x^p$ goes to $adx^p = 0$.

Comment: Googling gives this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.06039

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've seen this work but I don't understand how it answers my question.  Could you explain it? In work they say that the isomorphism lifts to the map of complexes in char = 0 but I don't need this. Actually, all I need is to understand the affine line case since I hope it will tell me a lot and it seems that this case should be simple but I don't see how to do it.

Comment: If all you need to do is to understand the case of the affine line, then the fact that the theorem holds for $X$ with $\dim X < p$ is enough: all primes are at least 2, and the RHS vanishes for $i>1$ by dimensionality reasons, and it's not hard to see that the map you want is defined all the time anyways.

Comment: @KReiser But I don't see why the theorem holds for X when p is large enough and what precisely is meant by the theorem. Since for any p the map from the first Hochschild homology of the affine line to the Kahler differentials which is given by (a \otimes b) \to adb is not an isomorphism by the reasons that I described in the post.

Comment: If you've verified that the given map and the anti-symmetrization map are indeed mutually inverse and that $a\otimes x^p$ maps to zero, then either you made a mistake or $a\otimes x^p=0$ in $HH_1$. I'm pretty sure it's the latter, but it's been long enough since I did much with this that I can't remember the whole explanation off the top of my head. I'll post an answer when I do.

Comment: @KReiser I think that they are mutually inverse by formal reasons. But you are right! $a \otimes x^p$ is zero indeed. For example, for $p=2$ we should take $a \otimes x \otimes x$ and it goes to $ax \otimes x - a \otimes x^2 + xa \otimes x = -a \otimes x^2$. I tried to do this before and failed but now I found it, thank you!